# Understanding newtonian gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

In gravitation that two object mutually attract applying equal forces on each other. But for instance if we take a disc and a solid sphere the fact that they have different gravitational fields on  on same distace, wouldnt they be applying different forces on each other?

Answer (score 2):

The fields are different but I would say you have to look to their interaction. The two objects A nd B might have a different mass and shape but if you look at the smallest relevant parts (the elementary particles with a mass > 0) then you see easily that for each of those "paricles" from A which "pulls" a "particle" from B the inverse is true too.

Just forget about the "big" objects A and B and just look at their components.

Answer (score 0):

Newton's gravitational law accounts for the mutual force acting between two point masses separated by some distance.For extended system we use the techniques in mathematics for the calculation of mutual gravitational force but the gravitational law is till valid if you calculate the mutual force acting between any two points on the two bodies.